# Pandoc equivalent to Sphinx's :download: role

Tags: python-sphinx, pandoc

Sphinx defines a role [`:download:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html?highlight=download#role-download) that instructs Sphinx to copy the reference file to `_downloads`.

Does Pandoc has a similar feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc does not have that feature built-in, but it [can be added](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters) with a few lines of Lua:

```lua
local prefix = 'media'
local path = pandoc.path

function Code (code)
  if code.attributes.role == 'download' then
    local description, filename = code.text:match '(.*) %<(.*)%>$'
    local mimetype, content = pandoc.mediabag.fetch(filename)
    local mediabag_filename = path.join{
      pandoc.utils.sha1(content),
      path.filename(filename)
    }
    if content and mimetype then
      pandoc.mediabag.insert(mediabag_filename, mimetype, content)
    end
    return pandoc.Link(description, path.join{prefix, mediabag_filename})
  end
end
```

Use the script by saving it to a file `download-role.lua` and the call pandoc with

```
pandoc --lua-filter=download-role.lua --extract-media=media ...
```

This will also work when using Markdown:

```markdown
`this example script <../example.py>`{role=download}
```